# Return values are not rendering correctly

Tags: jquery, html, listbox

When I want to render return values into a html listbox , the values are splitted after each character.

This is the jQuery code:

```
   $.get('GetBusiness.aspx', { Businessnr: Dossierno }, function (returndata) {
     // for each address in returndata
     $.each(returndata, function (val, text) {
        // add an option tag to the listbox id test
        $("#test").append(
           $("<option></option>").val(val).html(text)
        );
   });
```

My listbox does this:

```
i
t

r
e
n
d
e
r
```

What do I wrong ?

Comment: How your returndata looks like ?

Comment: it returns a string for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over an string:

```
>>> jQuery.each("hello", function(val, text) { console.log(val,text); });
0 h
1 e
2 l
3 l
4 o
```

Make sure what kind of data you expect to receive from `GetBusiness.aspx`. You can always check using `console.log`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try to put `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`